# When scroll last image display with Glide in android

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview, android-glide

I am using glide library and it's working perfectly. But problem is when i scroll the last image loads in display.Please share your experience. Thanks!

```
  Glide.with(activity).load(url_photo)
      .apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
      .into(iImageview);
```

I want to solve this problem.

This is my glide version.

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.0.1'
compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'
```

Comment: last images?. Can you post a picture for us understand whats happenning

Comment: Image is downloaded, before display

Answer (score 0):

You should add placeholder having default image to be shown when Images are loading. So when Glide request is made for an image it will immediately replace with placeholder image instead of previous image in a holder.

```
Glide.with(activity).load(url_photo)
  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
  .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
  .into(iImageview);
```

Use glide 3.7.0 if its not working on glide 3.8.0

Comment: Thanks, for your answered, But placeholder method is not came and not working. Other solution.

Comment: use glide 3.7.0 version

Comment: i used this version. 3.8.0

Comment: same issue is repeat, If you have other solution ?

Comment: Please edit your question again and add what you have done uptil now

Answer (score 0):

The `placeholder()` method is now part of `RequestOptions`. Usage:

```
 Glide.with(activity).load(url_photo)
  .apply(new RequestOptions()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.your_placeholder)
  .into(iImageview);
```

Refer to the [docs](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html#requestoptions) for more info.